# Outer glow in CMYK vs RGB

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, cmyk, rgb, blend-modes

I am creating this graphic in Illustrator and InDesign.
It is using an outer glow with the same magenta color as the fill of the shape. Normal blend mode 100% opacity.

I would like to get a similar glow result in CMYK as I get in the RGB version. I do know there are significant differences in the RGB and CMYK color spaces.

Still I was hoping there might be some tricks to achieve a less white glow.

Color values:

RGB: #e40045 on #303c49

CMYK: 0/100/60/0 on 63/32/14/76

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. It is unclear whether you're creating the effect in Illustrator or in Indesign. In case you did it in Indesign, you can change Transparency Blend Space to RGB: Edit > Transparency Blend Space. Be aware this will affect the whole document though.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I will try this and have a look at the printer’s results.

Comment: Thanks again. The trick with Blend Space was a good solution!

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be using a rich black and a fake *rich magenta* in a blend behind the magenta shape:

**Blend**

[image: blend]

**Top Shape**

[image: Top shape]

**Result**

[image: Glow]

**Add after the question edit**

It's obvious that if you want to get a good result you must create another color since the colors you are using have very different proportions of CYAN and BLACK; and knowing that none of the blending modes offers a good result.

One approach is to create blends between the base colors to their own light, 20% ink and blends of the resulting colors. This is to get a color that has the intermediate proportions of the absent CYAN and BLACK inks.

[image: blends]

Using the resulting color highlighted in the previous image, 47/49/26/57 we get a cyan and black percentage. Increasing the magenta to bring it closer to the top shape color and reducing the cyan:

- From **47**/**49**/26/57 to **30**/**75**/26/60

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.

Unfortunately I did’t clarify enough: the color values I used are specific brand colors. I can’t change them that much.

They are defined as the following:

RGB: #e40045 on #303c49
 
CMYK: 0/100/60/0 on 63/32/14/76

Comment: I was able to recreate the blends and got the same color value “47/49/26/57”. It is also clear to me why you increased the magenta.

The only thing I am missing right now is how you apply the new color.
If I create a shape with a 0/100/60/0 fill and the outer glow set to 30/75/26/60 and place it on the blue background it doesn’t look like your screenshot. It’s quite dull.

Are you creating some additional squares underneath?

Comment: I didn't use the outer glow. It's the blend from the blue to the new color and the magenta shape over, like the first part of the question.

Comment: Thanks again. I got it to work and the printing result is satisfying. But for this projects the option described below my question by @Vinny was more suitable.